# Android using LinearLayout as Background for all others LinearLayouts on the App

Tags: android, styles, themes, drawable, android-linearlayout

I have a LinearLayout with 2 others LinearLayouts inside. Each one of this it have an ImageView inside.
I need to set this LinearLayout as a Background for all the others LinearLayouts of my app.
I tried with "Include" and "Merge", but it didn't work, because I need to put other LinearLayout inside my "background LinearLayout"
Then i tried with "Styles", but I don't know how to add ImageViews inside LinearLayouts. It is possible?
Finally right now I'm trying with "Drawable", but I don't know if that the solution.

I need ideas, some help, can someone help me?

This is my "background LinearLayout":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@layout/gradient_background">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="170dip"> 

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/background_title"
        android:src="@drawable/titulo_fondo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="left|bottom"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-54dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-24dip"> 

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/background_logo"
        android:src="@drawable/circulo_logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout> 

</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks and sorry for my poor english

Answer (score 0):

Styles is probably the way to go, try creating a style like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/my_image</item>
</style>
```

and configure your entire app to use it be using the theme attribute in your manifest e.g.

```
<application
   android:icon="@drawable/icon"
   android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:theme="@style/MyTheme"
   ...
</application>
```

Comment: But I need to add 2 ImageViews to my Layout and each one have a diferent X,Y position. How I do that? Thanks